# Unable to print after update to Ubuntu 18.10 - brother DCP 7065DN USB

Tags: drivers, printing, brother, 18.10

I have a Brother DCP 7065DN printer connected by USB which stopped working after upgrading to Ubuntu 18.10.

Tried a variety of ways to fix the issue including Command line reinstall of driver

> apt-get purge cups
>
> apt-get install cups
>
> dpkg -i --force-all dcp7065dnlpr-2.1.0-1.i386.deb
>
> dpkg -i --force-all cupswrapperDCP7065DN-2.0.4-2.i386.deb
>
> dpkg -l | grep Brother

Everything looks fine on the output:

> ii  brscan-skey                                   0.2.4-1                                     amd64        Brother Linux scanner S-KEY tool
>
> ii  brscan4                                       0.4.6-1                                     amd64        Brother Scanner Driver
>
> ii  cupswrapperdcp7065dn:i386                     2.0.4-2                                     i386         Brother DCP7065DN CUPS wrapper driver
>
> ii  dcp7065dnlpr:i386                             2.1.0-1                                     i386         Brother DCP-7065DN LPR driver
>
> ii  printer-driver-brlaser                        4-1                                         amd64        printer driver for (some) Brother laser printers
>
> ii  printer-driver-ptouch                         1.4.2-3                                     amd64        printer driver Brother P-touch label printers

When I print a test page it looks like it works, print says receiving but nothing prints.  Same from a text editor.

Go to http://localhost:631/printers/Brother_DCP-7065DN - printed test page and same thing - looks to work but nothing prints.

If I manually remove/add the printer from the Ubuntu Device / Printers I get a different error message: stopped "Filter failed".

Also tried the RPM installer package, generic lpr and generic cups drivers from the Brother driver site but didn't work either.

Help!

Wull

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed issue with following commands:

sudo rmdir /usr/share/ghostscript/9.25/iccprofiles

sudo apt-get install --reinstall libgs9-common

Wull

Answer (score 1):

I tried the solution recommended above (reinstalling the  libgs9-common  library). It turned out I already have version 9.26 and the reinstall just put back the same version.
In any case, it didn't help. The problem persists.
I was able to confirm, however, that the problem is not in Libre Office: I downloaded a landscape document from another source (WPI_SampleLandscape.pdf) and the same behavior remained. The only workaround I could find was to rotate my landscape document to portrait orientation before printing it.